# Document root is not calling CSS

Tags: php

I do not know why this is not working. My header, footer, CSS and JS is not called when I am working in coffeeshop.php.

[Mysite](http://www.vouzalis.com/projects/coffeeShop.php)

I guess it is because it is not in the root folder. Therefore I made the include like this:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/navbar.php'; ?>
```

But is still not working?

[image: Code]

Here is where I put the full URL:

[image: Full url]

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the includes actually succeeded?

Comment: No, because I do not know how to do that? :-/

Comment: did you do a 'view source' in the browser to see if whatever html those scripts generate is present?

Comment: replace include with require, so that it raise an error if the files cannot be included.

Comment: When I use require I get an 500 error.

Comment: Voting to close as images are not a suitable format to supply code in. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers. Please always use a formatted code block instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is return folder path 

http://$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  it return server path
```

otherwise you can only use

```
<?php include '../resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include '../resources/includes/navbar.php'; ?>
```

try it

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Still not working.

Comment: No errors. Still the same, except that the menu is not there now

Comment: try include <?php include 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>

Comment: just uploaded the last one you suggested, still nothing. When I use the one you suggested, the menu is gone. But if I use : `"<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>"` , the menu is there, but no CSS and JS is called from the header and footer. But it includes the navigation etc

Comment: so the problem is not with the header being included, its with the header NOT pointing correctly to the JS and CSS?  Keep in mind, when an include references something, it does so assuming it is located in the file that included it.. in this case index.php, so even though header.php might be in a sub directory, the CSS and JS paths should be written as if it were in index.php  hope that makes sense.

Comment: where the menu  is included?

Comment: @Duane right...may be the problem in css and js path

Comment: This is the site: http://www.vouzalis.com/projects/coffeeShop.php . Menu is located in navbar.php. But I can see when I put in online the menu is disapering. On my localhost it is working with: `"<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vouzalis/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>"` , but that is not working online.

Comment: put full url and upload to server http://vouzalis.com/resources/includes/header.php

Comment: I have just updated my question with a screenshot, and I have also uploaded the version with full URL

Comment: still same :( issue

Comment: I just saw something.. There has to be a body tag between the header.php and the navbar.php. The navbar does not include a body tag, because I have an id on the body. Is that what is meaning with no wrapper? Not that it would solve the problem, but

Comment: add <body> tag in header.php of end file

Comment: also add full url in css and js

Comment: all css, js and includes in coffeeshop has full path now.